# Bootstrap select creates extra space when in flex box in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am trying to use a flex box to fill all the available vertical space inside a div.  Inside of the flex box I have a div that does not grow which contains a dropdown select.  In IE 11, when I click on the select, some extra space appears below the select.  This does not happen in Chrome or Edge, and I can not figure out where the space is coming from and how to prevent it.  I am using Bootstrap 3 to style the select.

Here's a simplified example:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 500px;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="form-group" style="background-color: yellow; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <label>Label</label>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>Yo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: orange;"></div>
</div>
```

I put this example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fq8m4abd/15/

In IE, when you click on the select, the yellow section gets larger, but remains the same in other browsers.

Is there a way to prevent this, or do I need to find a way to do this without flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the how IE11 is rendering the `display: inline-block` element for the `label` tag in con junction with the Flexbox. If you set your label to use `display: block` it will show correctly otherwise it shows underneath the select element below it.

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

Alternatively you could use `display: inline` as well. If I find any info on why this happens I will add it here. Seems like IE has pretty poor support with inline-block elements.

Comment: Thanks, `display: block` works great.  Making it inline removed some of the space between the label and inputs, making it look too squished.